# Distance between laser diode and photodetector

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, experimental-technique

I have a laser diode with a wide divergent elliptical beam (angles: 57°-13°).

If I want to use a light detector with 50mm diameter, how can I estimate the distance at which I can put the LD from the detector to have all the LD beam inside the detector?

I do not know the beam waist.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not know the beam waist.

The beam waist is almost certainly not important.

The reason the divergence is at such a high angle is that the waist diameter is very small. Likely less than a micron in the "out-of-plane" direction, leading to the 57° divergence in this direction.

If you just assume the waist is a point, and do the basic trigonometry for the 57° divergence, you'll get very close to the right answer.

But remember that 57° is not the angle of the cone that contains *all* the emitted power. It's probably the angle at which the emission intensity has fallen by half from the center of the beam. To get *all* of the emitted power, you'll want to make your detector diameter 2 or 3 times the diameter predicted by the 57° cone angle.